# Реализация связей между пользователями

Tags: php, mysql

Как лучше сделать, дружбу, заявки в друзья и чёрный список? Можно сделать всё в одну таблицу и друзей/заявки/чс заносит в качестве массива(но с учётом что постоянно его перезаписывать) или создать для каждой дружбы, чс отдельную строку, для каждой связи, и в случае отмены чс или дружбы удалять только одну связь, а не перезаписывать массив

Comment: отдельной таблицей: id-пользователя1, id-пользователя2, статус. где  статус что то вроде "чс", "заявка в друзья отправлена", "друзья", только конечно кодами какими нибудь, а не словами

Comment: Связь - одна сущность (неважно, заявка это или ЧС), значит, таблица тоже на всё про всё одна. А остальное уже сказал @Mike.

Comment: Как можно сделать регулярное выражение для проверки первых символов?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно такая структура.
И по поводу заявок в друзья.
2 аккаунта, назовём А и Б.
Когда А хочет подружиться с Б, создается одна запись в friends (user=A,friend=B), когда В подтверждает - создаем (user=B,friend=A).

```
users // Пользователи
 - id
 - login

friends // Друзья
 - id
 - user (users.id)
 - friend (users.id)

black_list // Черный список
 - id
 - user (users.id)
 - enemy (users.id)
```